# Assigning a variable value to another variable

Tags: javascript, variables, conditional-statements

1. how do i assign the conditional result
2. to a new variable (mostCars)? I want to solve for mostCars.

```js
cars = 3;
friendsCars = 4;
let mostCars = ?; 
//needs to be the value of the 
//greater of the two variables

if (friendsCars > cars || cars > friendsCars)
     //checking which 
     //is true
     {
        console.log( mostCars);
     }  
//assign the value of the true statement to mostCars.
```

The output should be the value of cars or friendsCars in a new variable mostCars. How do i go about to solving this??

Comment: Hi and welcome to Stack Overflow. Can you show us what you've tried and tell us what the error is? What did you try next? :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your code won't work, because it will enter to the `if` regardless which variable is greater (and skip it if the two values are equal).

Additionally, the if only logs the `mostCars`, which haven't value yet.

It can be done by `if`, but there is a better alternative:

The [`Math.max()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Math/max) method.

> The Math.max() function returns the largest of zero or more numbers.

So use that instead:

```js
let cars = 3;
let friendsCars = 4;
let mostCars = Math.max(cars, friendsCars); 

console.log(mostCars) //4
```